# JSONP PHP Array Empty

Tags: java, php, jsonp

im trying to get data via JSONP from my Webpage with a php script :

```
//connection and query above
 ...

 while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    //Add the fetched vale to $json array
    $json[] = $r;
     // Content type
  header("Content-type: application/json");
    echo "$callback({email: 'Message from Server.php'});";

  }



  // Content type
  header("Content-type: application/json");

  //JSONP - Make it as JSONP object


echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($json).")";
```

my `echo "$callback({email: 'Message from Server.php'});";` <--- works

but my
echo `$_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($json).")";` <--- returns null

when i call the script on my webpage like "page/callback.php"

i get following outputs in my Browser :

```
    ({email: 'Message from Server.php'});([{"0":"3","ID":"3","1":"dome","username":"dome","2":"vjvhrOWZYTq3qbrYfoE13A==","passwort":"vjvhrOWZYTq3qbrYfoE13A==","3":"mii@googlemail.com","email":"mii@googlemail.com","4":"0","active":"0","5":"hu","loc":"hu"}]

)
```

It contains -> "[" and "]"

my Java script is GWT :

```
        JsonpRequestBuilder jsonp = new JsonpRequestBuilder();
    jsonp.requestObject(URL.encode("http://webpage/callback.php?callback=test_clbk"), new AsyncCallback<JSONreceiver>() {
        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
            System.out.println(throwable.getMessage());
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void onSuccess(JSONreceiver result) {
            System.out.println(result.getResult());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Dear, are you echoing twice ? Or is it the two versions of the script? Personnaly, I use [Simple JSON for PHP](https://github.com/AlexisTM/Simple-Json-PHP) to forge a JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

You still do not have any answer.

Here is *one* solution :

1) Remove EVERY SINGLE echo / print / var_dump.

2) Initiate the json class with a callback

3) Forge your JSON with [Simple JSON for PHP](https://github.com/AlexisTM/Simple-Json-PHP)

4) Send your json at the end of the file

The results :

```
<?php

include('../includes/json.php');

// Set a callback
$json = new json('callback', 'mycallback');

// Forge your data
$json->add('email', 'message sent from Server.php');

while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $answer[] = $r;
}

// Forge your data
$json->add('data', $answer);
$json->add('status', '200');

// Send
$json->send();

?>
```